# Bigquery to PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

i need to push messages from bigquery to pubsbub

bigquery table contains a column with json value as a string

read that table and publish that to json

p.apply("ReadSourceBQ",
BigQueryIO
.readTableRows()
.fromQuery(
"SELECT requestPayload FROM eventreplay")
.usingStandardSql()
.withTemplateCompatibility()
).apply("JSON Transform", AsJsons.of(TableRow.class))
.apply("WriteToPubSub",
PubsubIO.writeStrings().to("topicname"));

its not publish msg to topic.. no error too. how to convert that tableRow to json

Comment: Are you executing `p.run();` after the preparation of your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the provided example should work.
Please make sure that you are running `p.run()`, as it is important to actually run the pipeline.

Here is a full example (using a public BigQuery dataset) that has worked for me:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
    pipeline
        .apply(
            "ReadSourceBQ",
            BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                .fromQuery("SELECT gameId FROM `bigquery-public-data`.`baseball`.`games_post_wide`")
                .usingStandardSql()
                .withTemplateCompatibility())
        .apply("JSON Transform", AsJsons.of(TableRow.class))
        .apply(
            "WriteToPubSub",
            PubsubIO.writeStrings().to("projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}"));

    pipeline.run();
  }
```

Also, please note that `AsJsons` comes from `beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson`, so you might have to import that using the following:

**Maven**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${beam.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson', version: '${beam.version}'
```